# Cannot find button element, but can find sibling elements

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver

Html is here (note - this part is nested in an iframe):

```
<div data-reactroot="">
  <div class="src-scenes-authenticated-components-sign-in-form-styles__main--I0vWu">
    <div class="src-scenes-authenticated-components-sign-in-form-styles__featureList--2RQdY"></div>
    <button class="src-components-button-styles__defaultButtonTheme--2-m2n src-components-button-styles__button--2hZHd">
      <div class="src-components-button-styles__content--28F4J">
         <div class="src-scenes-authenticated-components-sign-in-form-styles__signInButton--3AQAr">Sign In</div> 
      </div>  
    </button>
    <div class="src-scenes-authenticated-components-sign-in-form-styles__footer--1kMhz"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I've tried targeting the `<button>` element:

`.elementByXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div') // parent div of button
 .elementByXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]') // first child 
 .elementByXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]') // sibling AFTER button
 .elementByXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button') // error - NoSuchElement`

I've tried finding that button using `child::button`, and `following-sibling::button`...still no luck. I've also tried finding the `<div>` elements nested within the button. Still can't find it. I have also tried finding the button element after finding the first child (since it is the second child), still get the same error (NoSuchElement).

Another thing I tried was `.moveTo()`...which does work, but when I click on it nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Full test code here:

```
import wd, { asserters } from 'wd';
import configureLogging from './helpers/logging';
import { setup, config } from './helpers/config.js';

const {
  capabilities,
  testTimeout } = config;

export default function owaChromeLogin() {
  describe('Login flow via OWA for Chrome', function() {
    this.timeout(testTimeout);
    let driver;
    setup();

    before(function() {
      driver = wd.promiseChainRemote();
      configureLogging(driver);

      let desired = {
        ...capabilities.owa.chrome
      };

      return driver.init(desired);
    });

    after(function() {
      return driver;
      .quit();
    });


    // this is all to log into OWA AND the plugin
    it('should go to OWA and log in', function() {
      return driver
      .get('https://outlook.office365.com/owa/')
      .elementById('i0116') // username
      .type('****@****.onmicrosoft.com')
      .elementById('idSIButton9') // 'next' button
      .click()
      .waitForElementById('i0118', asserters.isDisplayed, 10000, 500) // password field...flaky - StaleElementReference
      .type('****')
      .elementById('idSIButton9') // 'sign in' button
      .click()
      .elementById('idSIButton9') // 'yes' button to stay signed in
      .click()
      .waitForElementByXPath('//*[@id="primaryContainer"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/button', asserters.isDisplayed, 5000, 300)
      .should.eventually.exist;
    });

    it('should click New Email', function() {
      return driver
      .elementByXPath('//*[@id="primaryContainer"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/button[1]')
      .click()
      .waitForElementByXPath('//*[@id="primaryContainer"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]', asserters.isDisplayed, 5000, 300)
      .should.eventually.exist;
    });

    it('should be able to open the Outreach plugin', function() {
      return driver
      // wait for AND click on Outreach logo button (bottom RH)
      .waitForElementByXPath('//*[@id="primaryContainer"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/button', asserters.isDisplayed, 5000, 300)
      .click()
      .waitForElementByXPath('/html/body/div[12]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[5]', asserters.isDisplayed, 5000, 300) // "Open Outreach"
      .click()
      // need to target items within iframe
      .waitForElementById('exttsp0', asserters.isDisplayed, 10000, 300) // iframe (parent)
      .elementByXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div') // parent div of button
      .elementByXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]') // first child
      .elementByXPath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button') // error - NoSuchElement
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Does your body have two `div` children? Your code does not show this...

Comment: Why `xpath`? When are you trying to find the button? What is the reactroot doing there? What framework is rendering your page? Could it be you are missing some info (or tags) to make it answerable?

Comment: @trincot - yeah, it does have two `div` children in the body. I only pasted in the html of the parent and children I'm trying to get. 

Wish I could post a screenshot, but leading up to the `data-reactroot` div  is...
<iframe> 
  <html>
    <head>
    <body>
       <div>
       <script>
       <div>
          <div data-reactroot></div>

Ugh, ugly and probably not clear. If it'll help to post the html leading up to it all, I can edit my original post.

Comment: @Icepickle - I'm using xpath now because I got the "NoSuchElement" error when I tried to find element by id. We are using React...if that answers your framework question?

Comment: Yeah, however it doesn't answer yet when do you want to find it (eg: on a click event, or when the page loads). Another question would be why you want to find it if it's part of the react rendering? What are you trying to do? Oh, I didn't see this was part of an automated UI test (probably), are you sure the page is rendered already at that time?

Comment: @Icepickle - ah. I'm trying to find a `Sign In` button as part of an automated test I am writing. My test is at the point where it has opened our plugin that we wrote for OWA (Outlook Web App). The side bar with our plugin opens, the sidebar has a `Sign In` button, and I need to click that `Sign In` button.

As for making sure the page is already rendered - yeah, I've also used `waitForElementByXPath(...)` and it times out, no element id is ever found.

Comment: Then, could you add the test code / steps? Are you sure it has rendered completely already? Can't you add a [testId](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-test-id) or another specific attribute that you can search for (except `id`)?

Comment: added test code! Have not added testId...will look into that next! 
Odd that `id` couldn't work...can't remember if I had already tried the `className`.

Comment: Well react tends to add it own `id` for the rendered elements, or at least it did, been a while since I checked into that. After checking that statement, I found out that in [React 16 `id` is supported](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes), so that was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

resolved! After watching my auto test run for the hundredth time, I realized the output of the `.waitForElementByXPath('xpath of parent element')` was providing several elements instead of just one. This was occurring before the iframe it exists in is loaded. So, I needed to add a time delay (sleep) before trying to target the iframe - `.frame(0)`...because its all in the first iframe for me), then I was able to target the button by id. I know using `.sleep()` isn't ideal, but I plan on circling back to that later.

Overall, here is what the test methods look like:

```
wd.addPromiseChainMethod('getSignInButton', function() {
  return this
    .sleep(3000)
    .frame(0)
    .waitForElementById('parentDiv', asserters.isDisplayed, 10000, 300)
    .elementById('signInButon')
    .click()
});
```